# Excel VBA transfer data to rows AND Columns

Tags: vba, excel

So, i have an problem with excel VBA. I have an input sheet and report sheet.
In data sheet i have table, with names, dates, and counts. I need to transfer that to other sheet. But i need names, each in new row, and the same data, which is typed in input sheet at all names in columns. I have already made everything for one row, but im stuck there.
Code so far :

```
Sub Ievades_poga()

Dim NewRow As Integer

NewRow = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("D7").Value + 1

If Worksheets("Ievade").Range("C7").Value <> 0 Then

MsgBox "Kļūda!", vbOKOnly, "123"

Exit Sub
End If

Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 1).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B3").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 2).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B4").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 3).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B5").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 4).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B6").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 5).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B7").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 6).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B8").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 8).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B9").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 9).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B10").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 10).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B11").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 11).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B12").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 12).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B13").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 13).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B14").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 14).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B15").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 15).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B16").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 16).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B17").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 17).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B18").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 18).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B19").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 19).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B20").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 20).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B21").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 21).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B22").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 22).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B23").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 23).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B24").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 24).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B25").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 25).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B26").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 26).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B27").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 27).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B28").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 28).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B29").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 29).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B30").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 30).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B31").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 31).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B32").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 32).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B33").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 33).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B34").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 34).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B35").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 35).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B36").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 36).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B37").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 37).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B38").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 38).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B39").Value
Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 39).Value = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B40").Value


MsgBox "Dati pievienoti!", vbOKOnly, "123"

Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B3").ClearContents

Worksheets("Ievade").Range("D7").Value = NewRow

Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B3").Select
End Sub
```

My input table is like this:

```
Name1   | Jhon
Name2   | Don
Name3   | Arthur
Name4   | Andrew
Date    | 19.06.2017
Number  | 435
Number  | 274
Number  | 814
```

And the report sheet should look like this:

```
Jhon    | 19.06.2017  | 435  | 274  | 814  |
Don     | 19.06.2017  | 435  | 274  | 814  |
Arthur  | 19.06.2017  | 435  | 274  | 814  |
Andrew  | 19.06.2017  | 435  | 274  | 814  |
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You should read about [loops](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1873/flow-control-structures) and [Transpose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheetfunction-transpose-method-excel).

Comment: I see no example of your data or desired output.  That makes it difficult to help you. Please edit your original question so as to provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you have more than one date per worksheet, and if yes, how are those supposed to be handled? Also, can you have multiple groups of names/dates/numbers; and if yes, how do you know which names are associated with which dates and which numbers?

Comment: Yes. I need to type every date there. So i need a function, that type in next data in new row, so the last data will be not overwrited. Each time i type in the names and data, i press confirm, and data will go to report sheet. Next time there will be other names, other dates and other numbers, that should go belove existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

The code would to be like this

```
Sub Ievades_poga()

Dim NewRow As Integer

NewRow = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("D7").Value + 1

If Worksheets("Ievade").Range("C7").Value <> 0 Then

MsgBox "K??da!", vbOKOnly, "123"

Exit Sub
End If

    Dim vDB
   vDB = Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B3").Resize(38)
   Worksheets("Lentzāģis").Cells(NewRow, 1).Resize(1, 38) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vDB)

MsgBox "Dati pievienoti!", vbOKOnly, "123"

Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B3").ClearContents

Worksheets("Ievade").Range("D7").Value = NewRow

Worksheets("Ievade").Range("B3").Select
End Sub
```